# Ripple effect on custom navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I'm developing my first app providing to it the new material look. I'm a bit lost with this so I'm following some tutorials to implement things like Toolbar, Navigation Drawer, etc. I have to say that I'm doing it providing compatibility to pre-lollipop android versions, so I'm using support libraries.

What concers to my question, is that I have just implemented the Navigation Drawer following one of this tutorials and using the following libraries for compatibility:

```
support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

I think that the code implementation is too long to put it here, so I'll provide the link to this tutorial, I have done it exactly as is said [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/).

My problem is that, when I select one item from the navigation drawer's row, it perfectly opens it correspondant frament, but, it doesn't show any ripple effect, or simply any touch effect, when touching it. Something like this:

[image]

I have taken a look to some other tutorials, for example, to the one to which belongs the attached gif, to see if they use any method or implementation to provide that efect to the touch, but nothing is implemented to get that effect, just the onclick method.

So, what's wrong with this code, and how could I modify it, or what could I add to get that effect?

Comment: Which device are you testing it in? I have always designed the drawables with the ripple specifically for Lollipop devices, keeping the old `Selector` implementation for the older versions. Are you testing on a pre-L device?

Comment: @SlashG I'm testing on booth pre-lollipop(KitKat) and lollipop(5.0)

Comment: Have you specified the Material theme for your app in `drawable/values-v21/style.xml`?

Comment: @SlashG nope, as I'm following the compatibility pattern, I have to use the AppCompat style, and I have stiled the app as said in the tutorial.

Comment: For me, ripples work only with Material. I'm not sure of the `AppCompat` library for it. If you think `AppCompat` has the `Ripple` in it, you could try updating your Support Library and re-importing it. Otherwise, you can make ripples available for Lollipop only, by defining styles specifically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are using appcompat you can add this to the XML for your navigation drawer item `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`.

This should provide the ripple effect on Lollipop devices and a fallback grey highlight for older devices.

Comment: With this you have to add your preferred color when touch on drawer items by add this to your styles.xml `<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ruler</item>` which has `AppTheme.NoActionBar`